# How can I access value of a variable from another source file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, extern

I am using codeblockide.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include "adduser.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    adduser();
    user();
    cout<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

adduser.cpp

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int adduser()
{
    string name,pass;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("test.txt");
    cout<<"Enter The Name : ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter The Password : ";
    cin>>pass;
    fout<<name<<","<<pass<<endl;
    fout.close();
    return 0;

}
```

adduser.h

```
#ifndef ADDUSER_H_INCLUDED
#define ADDUSER_H_INCLUDED

extern std::string name;
int adduser();

#endif // ADDUSER_H_INCLUDED
```

I want to access the string variable "name" from the adduser.cpp file and print it on main.cpp

I searched for "how to access variable from another source file" and get "extern" keyword.

I used "extern" but I didn't get what I expected, it displays nothing.

But this is not working here. Am I doing wrong?
How can I do that?

Comment: You can, but you should not. Pass the name as a parameter to adduser (you need to change the paraneter list).

Comment: I think you're greatly misunderstanding C++'s scoping rules and the concept of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to access a variable local to the function `adduser()` from another function, this is not allowed in C++.
In addition, the declaration of `string name` in `main()` hides the definition of `name` in `adduser.hpp`

You have several options here:

- Move `name` outside of `adduser()` to before the function
- Change the return type of `adduser()` to `std::string` and place `return name` at the and change the call for `adduser()` in `main` with `name = adduser()`
- Add a parameter `std::string& name` or `st::string* name` to `adduser()` and call `adduser()` in `main` with `adduser(name)` or `adduser(&name)` respectively